# функция выделяющая второй, третий и четвертый разряд переданного числа

Tags: алгоритм

нужна функция выделяющая  второй, третий и четвертый разряд переданного числа.
Например:

```
mid(123456)=345
mid(169)=16
mid(625)=62
mid(555025)=502
```

Должно решаться через  деление и взятие остатка от деления. Не могу сообразить как это сделать.

Comment: Как можно при наличии `Должно решаться через деление и взятие остатка от деления.` в вопросе, не осознать решение?

Comment: @alexolut, очень просто: это типичный вопрос из серии "_сделайте за меня_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(x / 10)%1000
```

Вполне подходит под условие.

Comment: для плавающей точки - преобразовать частное (x/10) к типу int.

Answer (score 5):

В языках программирования с целыми и «плавающими» числами существуют две операции деления: целочисленное и для чисел с плавающей точкой.

Если в наличии есть целочисленное деление, то надо разделить на 10 (убрать самый младший разряд), затем взять остаток от деления на 1000 (у оставшегося числа взять три младших цифры). Это решение привёл @pavel.

Если в наличии только деление с плавающей точкой, то операция чуть усложняется: надо из основного числа вычесть остаток от деления его на 10, тогда в конце него окажется точно 0. После этого делите на десять и берите остаток от деления на 1000 — всё, как раньше.